# proof the distance of points

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

There are more than 1000000 points in the space, if we calculate the distance between each 2 of them, prove that we will have more than 78 different distances. (there will be more than 78 different numbers)

Comment: My first thought would be to consider what this means for all the different distances from one point. And then another. And then...

Comment: lets assume the worst condition, one point in the center of a sphere, and all of the other points are on the surface of the sphere , can i reach something with this assuming?

Comment: Is that 3 dimensional space ?

Comment: yes , I think its 3D

Comment: Have you tried some small numbers?  For example, $4$ points can have all mutual distances the same.  That makes me thinking about [**Thomson problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem).

Comment: yes , I was thinking about Regular polyhedron , but i didn't find anything